# NATゲートウェイとsquidの違いはなんでしょうか？またよりセキュアなのはどちらでしょうか？

Tags: aws, proxy, squid

### 疑問点

AWSのNATゲートウェイとsquidの違いを明確にしたいです。
また、どちらの方がよりセキュアかご教授願います。

### 調べたこと

- NATゲートウェイ
  プライベートサブネットからインターネットに向けた通信とそのレスポンス時にIPアドレスを変換するサービス
- squid
  プロキシ機能を持つソフトウェアでアドレス変換はしない、あくまで転送の役割

といったところかと思いました。

### 質問

どちらも中継役としての役割でセキュアだと思うのですが、よりセキュアなのはどちらなのかと疑問に思いました。
状況によって変わるかとは思いますが、どういった場合どちらを選ぶべきかご教授願います。
そもそもの解釈間違いなどご指摘、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NATゲートウェイ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html#nat-gateway-basics)は、TCP、UDP、ICMPのアドレス変換するのに対し、[squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Intro/)はHTTP/1.0とHTTP/1.1のみとなっていて、扱う対象が全く異なります。

> ・squid→プロキシ機能を持つソフトウェアでアドレス変換はしない、あくまで転送の役割

いいえアドレス変換します。squidがいったんリクエストを受信し、ヒットするキャッシュがあればリクエストを転送せずに応答を返します。ヒットしない場合はsquidからリクエストが出されるため、アドレスが変換されます。
（厳密にはtransparent proxyモードもありますが…）

> よりセキュアなのはどちらなのか

は「セキュア」の定義を明確にする必要があります。

その上で一つ言えることは、[AWSの責任共有モデル](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/)においてNATゲートウェイはAWSの責任を負うリソースだということです。

Comment: squidの理解を修正できました！
ちなみになのですが、HTTP/1.0はあくまでHTTPのバージョンであってHTTPSとは別物と解釈してよいでしょうか？